# how to merge/combine two array and create a new row in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
data1 = [{
 row: 1,
 name: 'edward'
}];

data2 = [{
 row: 1,
 style: 'style 1'
},{
 row: 2,
 style: 'style 2'
},{
 row: 3,
 style: 'style 3'
}];
```

What I'm trying to do is to combine/merge the data and create a new row. I try to use the filter but it doesn't display the data row2 and row3. cause the from the data1 it has only 1 row.

here's the expected output

```
[{
    row: 1, data1: { name: 'edward' }, data2: { style: 'style 1' }
},{
    row: 2, data1: { }, data2: { style: 'style 2' }
},{
    row: 3, data1: { }, data2: { style: 'style 3' }
}];
```

and then when there's a new data from data1 it should be added.
example:

```
{ row: 5, name: 'juan' }
```

it should be like this:

```
[{
    row: 1, data1: { name: 'edward' }, data2: { style: 'style 1' }
},{
    row: 5, data1: { name: 'juan' }, data2: { }
},{
    row: 2, data1: { }, data2: { style: 'style 2' }
},{
    row: 3, data1: { }, data2: { style: 'style 3' }
}];
```

code that I tried:

```
const data = this.data1.filter((x: any) => this.data2.map((y: any) => y.row === x.row));
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @kai I added the code

Answer (score 0):

Try This out

```js
data1 = [
{row: 1,name: 'edward'},
{ row: 5,name: 'juan' } 
];

data2 = [
{
 row: 1,
 style: 'style 1'
},{
 row: 2,
 style: 'style 2'
},{
 row: 3,
 style: 'style 3'
}];

function mergeData(data1,data2){
  hashDataOne = {};
  mergedArray = [];
  data1.forEach(ele =>{
    hashDataOne[ele.row] = ele.name;
  });
  
  data2.forEach(ele =>{
    if(ele.row in hashDataOne){
      mergedArray.push({
        row: ele.row,
        data2:{style:ele.style},
        data1:{name:hashDataOne[ele.row]}
      });
      delete hashDataOne[ele.row]; 
    } else {
      mergedArray.push({
        row: ele.row,
        data2:{style:ele.style},
        data1:{}
      });    
    }
  });
  
  for(const row in hashDataOne){
      mergedArray.push({
        row: row,
        data2:{},
        data1:{name: hashDataOne[row]}
      });    
  }
   
  return mergedArray;
}

console.log(mergeData(data1,data2));
```

Comment: I added a new data on data1 but it didn't display the new data

Comment: for example if there's a new data from data1 and data2 it should be added if their row number is same it will merge

Comment: Just add const before row. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-haqr2m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score -2):

Try like `merge` function below. Added explanation to code.

I've created new function `getMergeResult`. Once you `add/update/delete` record from `data1` or `data2` you can call it and get updated `array`.

```js
// it will merge records from data array based on row value.
// use property name to assign value of data to result object.
// result is optional. function will return result array 
// or you can pass result to function as it is reference type it will updated.
function merge(data, name, result = []) {
  // loop over data
  data.forEach(d => {
    // find object for row exists in result.
    let obj = result.filter(r => r.row === d.row)[0];
    // if obj is null then create new object and push to array.
    if (!obj) {
      obj = { row: d.row, data1: {}, data2: {} };
      result.push(obj);
    }
    // assign properties values to obj["data1"] or obj["data2"] with use of name parameter.
    Object.assign(obj[name], d);
    // remove row property from obj["data1"] or obj["data2"].
    delete obj[name].row;
  });
  // return result.
  return result;
}

function getMergeResult(data1, data2) {
  let result = merge(data1, 'data1');
  merge(data2, 'data2', result);
  return result;
}

let data1 = [{
  row: 1,
  name: 'edward'
}];

let data2 = [{
  row: 1,
  style: 'style 1'
}, {
  row: 2,
  style: 'style 2'
}, {
  row: 3,
  style: 'style 3'
}];

console.log("Initial result");
console.log(getMergeResult(data1, data2));

console.log("Push new record");
data1.push({ row: 5, name: 'juan' });

console.log("New result");
console.log(getMergeResult(data1, data2));
```